# Windows cmd curl command with usrname and password

Tags: windows, curl, cmd

I  try to access my yahoo account with curl command under Windows 7 cmd with username and password with the following syntax:

curl -u username@ymail.com:password http://yahoo.com

but I get the following:

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

on Windows, use **nslookup yahoo.com** to determine if you can successfully resolve the host.  On Linux or MAC you can use **dig yahoo.com**.  You should see below using dig.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.2 <<>> yahoo.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45453
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;yahoo.com.                     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
yahoo.com.              1771    IN      A       206.190.36.45
yahoo.com.              1771    IN      A       98.138.253.109
yahoo.com.              1771    IN      A       98.139.183.24

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#53(192.168.0.13)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 23 10:26:51 Eastern Daylight Time 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 86
```

and using nslookup:

```
C:\local\BIND9.10.2.x64>nslookup yahoo.com
Server:         xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Address:        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 98.139.183.24
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 206.190.36.45
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 98.138.253.109
```

Or try using the **ping yahoo.com** command to see what's going on.

Comment: ping www.google.com  returns the following: Ping could not find host

Comment: try - assuming this is a windows machine, **ipconfig /all** and see what the option under _Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection_ says next to _DNS Servers_.  You need to find out if your network adminstrator provides DNS servers via DHCP or sets them statically.  It's also possible that this machine doesn't have network access for a reason, so make sure that you speak to your network administrator before making changes.  If you don't have internal DNS and this machine doesn't need it, you can use Google's DNS public servers at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 four outside resolution.